# How to restrict the Case or Queue so that, the Case can not be visible in each queues?

Tags: apex, lightning, community, case, assignment-rules

I have created multiple queues for teams. When I create a case, it is visible to each queue and members. I have also made changes in Sharing Settings for case object and made it Private.
    If anyone has an idea to restrict the case or the queue then it will be great for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you are trying to do? What restrictions are you attempting to add? (Please [edit])